# ADF-pipeline onfailure not working for throtling expections

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

Please check above image where highlighted with yellow that get processed activity on failure connected with drop table  but its not working  and its not even triggering when expection like throtling in get processed activity

Help to trigger the drop table for get proccesed activity on failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure data explorer command **Drop table** activity will be executed when Azure Data explorer command **Get Alerts from Processed Table** activity is failed **and** Lookup activity is failed **and** For-each activity is succeeded.

[image]

The solution is to have DROP TABLE activity thrice. One upon failure of  **Get Alerts from Processed table** Azure data explorer command activity and second one on failure of lookup activity and the other one upon success of For-each activity.

[image]

Comment: Aswin Are u saying me add three drop table command for each on failure right?

Comment: Yes. Add Drop table activity in every activity

Comment: Refer the second image in the answer.

Comment: cant open the image sorry

Comment: Could you try checking this answer/image in the mobile or any other device?

Comment: Thanks so much Aswin, just to understand we cant use single drop command for all the three , since same drop command only

Comment: If we do so, drop command will execute when all three activities got executed only.